# Liquibase: managing Master Data

Tags: liquibase

I am using liquibase in my project.

I have **tenant** table with **tenant_id** as primary key. And the remaining tables have tenant_id as a column.

Now what will be the better way to handle **master data** with **different tenants**

**Tables:**

```
<createTable tableName="tenant">
  <column name="tenant_id" autoIncrement="true" type="int">
     <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"
      primaryKeyName="pk_tenant_id" />
  </column>
  <column name="name" type="varchar(100)"></column>
</createTable>

<createTable tableName="base_entity">
  <column name="base_entity_id" autoIncrement="true" type="int">
<constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"
primaryKeyName="pk_base_entity_id" />
  </column>
<column name="tenant_id" type="int">
<constraints nullable="false" />
</column>
</createTable>
```

**-- Data: --** 
Currently I am handling data like this

```
 <property name="@tenant_id_1"
 value="(select tenant_id from tenant where name='test1') " dbms="mysql" />

 <property name="@tenant_id_2"
 value="(select tenant_id from tenant where name='test2') " dbms="mysql" />


<insert tableName="tenant">
<column name="name">test1</column>
</insert>

<insert tableName="tenant">
<column name="name">test2</column>
</insert>

<insert tableName="base_entity">
<column name="name">testBase_Entity</column>
<column name="tenant_id" valueComputed="${@tenant_id_1}" />
</insert>

<insert tableName="base_entity">
<column name="name">testBase_Entity</column>
<column name="tenant_id" valueComputed="${@tenant_id_2}" />
</insert>
```

**But I have 'n' no of tenants, for every entry of tenant I've to insert the data.**

Is there any option in liquibase do this in a better way ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: While liquibase can manage different sets of data using contexts, it is difficult to manage dynamic table relationships are you're trying to do. dbunit on the other hand has methods to ensure a consistent dataset is loaded each time. Might be what you're looking for See: http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/  Use liquibase for schema management and dbunit for more complex table population.